# How to log and block all internet access from a program?

Tags: logs, network-interface, jails

I have a binary from an untrusted source, and I would like to block and log any internet access attempt, and see to what server it tries to connect.

A first way I though of is using firejail https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/firejail, but I would need to have a fake virtual net interface that logs everything I guess.

Do you have other solution, or do you know how to do such a virtual interface ?

Comment: What OS (Linux, BSD), distro and version?

Comment: OS = Archlinux (rolling)

Comment: Has Google stopped working? https://www.google.com/search?q=application+level+firewall+linux

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov You still need to guess the right keywords... (thanks by the way, because no other search I did resulted in opensnitch)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to this google search suggested as comment : google.com/search?q=application+level+firewall+linux

I found opensnitch that does exactly what I needed:
Just to install it, and enable the service. It will throw a popup anytime a program tries to access internet.